# Knockout JS and DataTables Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, datatables

```js
function Lead(data){
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.number = ko.observable(data.mobile);
    this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
    this.return_date = ko.observable(data.return_date);
    this.advert = ko.observable(data.advert);
    this.date_enquired = ko.observable(data.date);

}

function leadView(){
   var self = this;
   
   self.leads = ko.observableArray([]);
   
    $.getJSON('ajax/leads.php', function(data){
            
            var mapped = $.map(data, function(info){
                return new Lead(info);
            });
            
            self.leads(mapped);
            
            var dt = $('#lead-table').DataTable({
                        dom: "tip",
                        ordering: false,
                        bProcessing: true,
                        data: self.leads(),
                        columns: [
                            {data: 'name()' },
                            {data: 'number()' },
                            {data: 'email()' },
                            {data: 'return_date()' },
                            {data: 'advert()' },
                            {data: 'date_enquired()' }
                        ]
                    });
        });

    self.update = function(){
        $.getJSON('leads.php', function(data){
            
            var mapped = $.map(data, function(info){
                return new Lead(info);
            });
            
            self.leads(mapped);
        });
     
    }
    
}

var DataLeadView = new leadView();

window.setInterval(DataLeadView.update, 5000);
ko.applyBindings(DataLeadView);
```

i have this code which is printing out my table just fine using Knockout JS and DataTables, i have a counter which shows the total number of leads.

then i run my function to update the leads() observableArray;
that updates the counter but not the table
so my question is how do i get the table to add the row thats just been added to the array?

Comment: can you make us a repo in fiddle so we can help on it . cheers

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n3m89ntj/
Im not quite sure how i use this but normally the data is retrieved by getJSON and then inserted into the observableArray() it updates the counter but not the table

Comment: you have to redraw the table if any changes like appending/deleting etc i.e `dt.draw()` if you want to clear `dt.clear().draw()` . cheers

Comment: Where do i put the dt.clear().draw() ?

Comment: inside your update function and you can see table is cleared . check the sample fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/n3m89ntj/7/ . cheers

Comment: Ah Okay thank you, but when i put it in my solution i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear' of undefined

Comment: i have to take a guess here may be because you are not using datatables version 1.10.5 . its works pretty much well in fiddle .

Comment: i am using that version of dataTables yeah, in your fiddle when you put mapped back in leads observable it adds the counter back but doesnt redraw the table? or im just doing it wrong, sorry for this im abit of a noob

Comment: you have to follow some steps here like `dt.clear()` next `dt.row.add(//your data)` finally call `dt.draw` . If you fill `self.leads(//updated data)` that doesn't mean on call of draw table gets updated . you need to build source and call draw table .

Comment: do refer the doc's on `add()` here http://datatables.net/reference/api/ .

Comment: here is a sample for you how to do a `add()` http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/n3m89ntj/13/ . cheers .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/simon1709/n3m89ntj/14/ I think this is the solution i'm looking for thank you for your help. much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to redraw the table using `draw` to show your updated changes

**Code :**

```
self.update = function () {

            var mapped = $.map(data, function (info) {
                return new Lead(info);
            });

            self.leads(mapped);
            dt.clear(); // clear table
            dt.rows.add(self.leads()); // build the source again by adding
            dt.draw() ; // draw table with added rows
        }
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/n3m89ntj/16/)**